# Primitive properties initialization in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, initialization

I have immutable `Int` property which value is caclulated in the constructor.Something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    val myProperty:Int
    init{
        //some calculations
        myProperty=calculatedValue
    }
}
```

But this code won't compile.Compiler says `Property must be initialized or be abstract`.I can't initialize it as it's value will be known only after class instantiation.Looks like kotlin forces me to have the property mutable.Is this the only way?
UPD:I just realized I was assigning property value inside `for` loop which leads to `unable to reassign val property` error.This topic is subject for deletion.Sorry.

Comment: Please post full code in `init`. Like this, I have no problem with initializing the property.

Comment: @Maroš Šeleng The problem occurs only for primitive types as they must be initialized right after declaration

Comment: I see no issue: [example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJmb2xkZWRCdXR0b24iOnRydWUsInJlYWRPbmx5IjpmYWxzZSwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBhID0gQSgpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihcImEuaSA9ICR7YS5pfVwiKVxufVxuXG5jbGFzcyBBIHtcbiAgICB2YWwgaTogSW50XG5cbiAgICBpbml0IHtcbiAgICAgICAgaSA9IDkgKyAzMFxuICAgIH1cbn0ifQ==).

Comment: I realize you have accepted an answer, but what you're doing in your question should work with no issues. Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. What version of Kotlin are you using?

Comment: @slaw see updated initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing it while initialization?

```
class MyClass {
    val myProperty: Int = calcMyProperty() // use that if the calculation is complex
    val myOtherProperty: Int = 5 + 3 // use that if the calculation is simple

    private fun calcMyProperty(): Int {
        // some very complex calculation
        return 5 + 3
    }
}
```

Comment: will calcMyProperty be called after init block?

Comment: That is wrong @IEE1394. Kotlin will execute property initializations and init blocks in the order that they are defined.

Comment: @marstran indeed.I made it work by moving declaration below the init block.This make answer accepted :)

Comment: @marstran .. cool .. didn't know that .. makes it a lot more easier

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `run` function. You `val` will be initialized with the value that is returned from the lambda (the last expression). Like this:

```
class MyClass {

    val myProperty: Int = run {
        //some calculations
        calculatedValue
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The acceptable answer is to use private setter:

```
class MyClass {
    var myProperty:Int=0
       private set
    init{
        //some calculations
        myProperty=calculatedValue
    }
}
```

However there is still chance to reassign wrong value inside the class